# Authority check with Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a system to do with express.js, but I had difficulty.
I want to do something like this.

Middleware;

```
module.exports = {

AuthorityCheck: function(req, res, next) {
//console.log(/*Where I get the roles*/)
//
}

}
```

Routes;

```
routes.get('/admin', AuthorityCheck['role','role2'], (req, res, next) => {
res.render('admin/index.html')
})
```

How do I get the roles given in AuthorityCheck?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `AuthorityCheck` return another function that closes over the two role arguments, then when you use the middleware, pass your roles to your function. Here I am using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to make the syntax a little more concise, but you can use regular function expressions if you wish:

```
module.exports = {
  AuthorityCheck: (role1, role2) => (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(role1, role2);
  }
}
```

And to use it, call your AuthorityCheck function by passing it the roles, which will return your middleware function that has access to those roles:

```
routes.get('/admin', AuthorityCheck('role','role2'), (req, res, next) => {
```

---

If you want to be able to pass in *N* roles into your `AuthorityCheck` function and not just two like in the above example, you can use the [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), where `roles` will now be an array of all the arguments passed into the `AuthorityCheck` function:

```
AuthorityCheck: (...roles) => (req, res, next) => {
```